# VAR estimation-How to interpret the results?

Tags: r, regression, estimation, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I have these results when I estimate a VAR with two variables:Growth and Debt and p=2.How to interpret the result for each equation? Thank you.

## VAR Estimation Results:

```
Endogenous variables: Growth, Debt 
Deterministic variables: const 
Sample size: 21 
Log Likelihood: -106.915 
Roots of the characteristic polynomial:
0.4555 0.4555 0.3236 0.1897
Call:
VAR(y = newdata, p = 2, type = "const")
```

## Estimation results for equation Growth:

```
Growth = Growth.l1 + Debt.l1 + Growth.l2 + Debt.l2 + const 

          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
Growth.l1 -0.51486    0.31247  -1.648   0.1189  
Debt.l1   -0.83960    0.29895  -2.809   0.0126 *
Growth.l2  0.09635    0.29514   0.326   0.7483  
Debt.l2    0.10281    0.31715   0.324   0.7500  
const      6.12191    2.24173   2.731   0.0148 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Residual standard error: 3.976 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.3729, Adjusted R-squared: 0.2162 
F-statistic: 2.379 on 4 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.09521
```

## Estimation results for equation Debt:

```
Debt = Growth.l1 + Debt.l1 + Growth.l2 + Debt.l2 + const 

           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
Growth.l1  0.731897   0.314552   2.327   0.0334 *
Debt.l1    0.619108   0.300940   2.057   0.0563 .
Growth.l2  0.007834   0.297111   0.026   0.9793  
Debt.l2    0.140517   0.319265   0.440   0.6657  
const     -3.443299   2.256689  -1.526   0.1466  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Residual standard error: 4.003 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.2981, Adjusted R-squared: 0.1227 
F-statistic: 1.699 on 4 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.1993 

Covariance matrix of residuals:
       Growth   Debt
Growth 15.809 -9.857
Debt   -9.857 16.021

Correlation matrix of residuals:
        Growth    Debt
Growth  1.0000 -0.6194
Debt   -0.6194  1.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to interpret a VAR Model would be to calculate the impulse response functions and plot them. They show you how one variable reacts when a shock hits the system. (see `?irf`)

```
imp<-irf(YOUR_MODEL)
plot(imp)
```

by the way: Maybe you **cant** estimate a valid model with such a low number of observations.